# applying a function within ddply

Tags: r

I'm tryin to apply a group-wise function using ddply.
My data looks like that:

https://echange-fichiers.inra.fr/get?k=b1jD63CWkT93hDsbZ0g

The following function calculates x value for y=0

```
intercept=function (x,y){

    if (length(y[y==0])==0){
      x1=min(x[y >0])
      y1=min(y[y >0])

      x2=max(x[y <0])
      y2=max(y[y <0])

      p =(y2-y1)/(x2-x1)

      x0= -y1/p + x1

    }else{
      x0=x[y==0]

    }
return(x0)
}
```

then I try to apply this by group with ddply:

```
zzz=ddply(Data,.(Genotype,T), summarise
         InterDays=(intercept(Data$Days,Data$Diff)) 
)
```

My grammar must be wrong since it does no not return a output with a similar format than :

```
zzz=ddply(DataAll,.(Genotype,T), summarise
         InterDays=mean(DataAll$Days) 
)
```

I think there is something wrong with the way I call my function variables but I don't see where...
Any help welcome.
All the best,
Vincent

Comment: Both your code are missing a `,` after `summarise`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should call `ddply` this way :

```
ddply(Data,.(Genotype,T), summarise,
         InterDays=(intercept(Days,Diff)) 
)
```

IIUC, if you call your intercept function with `Data$Days` and `Data$Diff` as arguments, the whole vectors will be passed to the function each time. With `Days` and `Diff`, only the values corresponding to the current subset of `Data` is used.

Comment: @user2075072 If it solved your problem, you can check the green mark to show it to other users.

Comment: @user2075072, it is important to note the difference juba mentions about accessing columns of your data.frame as `variables` inside `summarise`. Else you're taking the whole column. And you should mark this as answered.